# Jmeter - Extract id value from url with xpath

Tags: xpath, jmeter, extractor

I've the following URL 
https://x.x.x.x/x/continue?processId=1234567&formAction=register

I need to extract the proccessId to use in the following request, but in JMeter with XPATH extractor value

```
//*[@id="signupForm"]
```

I can't recover the value, is there any option to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Easier to use [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) for fetching value from URL

Add as a Post Processor of request Regular Expression Extractor with values:

```
 Regular Expression: `processId=(\d+)&formAction=register`

 Template `$1$` (indicate first group)

 Match No. `1` ( fetch the first number)

 Reference Name: `yourVariableName`
```

and then use `${yourVariableName}` in your next request(s).

Note: If you are extracting from Request's URL you need to choose `URL` in `Field to Check` radio buttons.